# What should our chatroom be named?

Tags: discussion, chat

Currently, our chatroom has the (rather unexciting) name 'Colloquium'. In my opinion, we should not be using a common ancient Roman phrase for this modern site. What should our chatroom be named?

Format:

> ### Foo Bar
>
> Because we all like to foo bars!

Answer (score 16):

## The Observatory

Maybe too obvious, but I like it.

Comment: That would be a wicked name for a mod-only chat room. Freaky ;-)

Comment: Yes, this *has* to be for the mod chat room.

Answer (score 7):

## Cosmic Background

I.e. the *radiant* bunch.

Comment: Heh... I see what you did there.

Answer (score 6):

### [Milliways](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Milliways)

It's when we are going anyway. Why not be early?

Comment: Reserve me a spot next to the Halfrunt party...

Answer (score 2):

## The Local Cluster

Our best known stellar neighborhood.

Answer (score 0):

**The Black Hole**

It sucks you into chat.

Answer (score -1):

### The Sombrero Galaxy

ref: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/815/conversation/the-sombrero-galaxy

Comment: Please please please! I even changed my display name for this one!

Comment: As someone who is haunted regularly by an elderly lady wearing a sombrero, I approve.

Answer (score -3):

## Learning by Cosmosis

It's how astronomers make discoveries